# IAP available in sandbox, but can not fetch it using "product id" after the app get online in appstore

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have tested all my IAP product in the sandbox environment, but after the app been approved by Apple's review team, it just do not work:
I downloaded and installed my app from the appstore, when I pressed the product, my app tried to fetch the product's information using the "product id" but got 0 result.

Then I deleted the app, and installed it using the Xcode, and the app worked pretty well, as you know, at this time it connected to the andbox.itunes.apple.com environment.

Does anyone have met such a problem? Can you help me please?

Comment: same here. just published; approved by App Store. all worked well when testing in sandbox mode. now IAPs are not available, for 2 days already :( Apple ain't getting money either i would say..?!

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing exactly same issue right now. Having in mind you are asking same question 15 mins earlier than me, I may suggest this is something going weird on Apple's servers. I have googled this and looked for the similar questions here, and it appears that it takes some time before IAP are available. So I dropped message to Apple support, but I guess we need just wait some time.

Comment: Absolutely, I waited about 2 days before the IAP became available in the production environment. Everything is OK now!

Comment: Well, mine was resolved this night. If not yours, I can suggest checklist mentioned in every IAP question: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ I'm sure you know about it. The worst thing about IAP you can never know the exact reason either yours or Apple's. I feel like thousands of developers praying reason would be easier to track.

Answer (score 1):

Anybody met such a problem just have to wait for 2 days, be patient, this is an issue of Apple itself!